# Android youtube player activity inside oncreateoptionsmenu using

Tags: java, android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api, android-videoview

I using video view for youtube videos but `OnCreateOptionsMenu` not running. How to use not used youtubeplayerfragment? Is the YouTubeBaseActivity inside support use ?

This videoactivity.class

```
public class videoactivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity{

@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean loadAgain) {

    if (!loadAgain) {
        youTubePlayer.cueVideo(ID_VIDEO);
    }
}

@Override
public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

  }

}
```

and `OnCreateOptionsMenu` method:

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.video_menu, menu);


    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case android.R.id.home:

            super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

            this.finish();
            goBackWithAnimation();
            break;
        case R.id.share_button:
            showShareOptions();
            break;


    }

    return true;
 }
```

but not running. How to use?

Comment: I tried in my class which extends `YouTubeBaseActivity`, and it works. Have you set the style/theme that has an `ActionBar` or `Toolbar` which contains menu, and it will call the method.

Comment: Thank you for answer bro,have you example?

Comment: Sure, I can upload the project to my github. you can try it yourself, hold on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried in my class which extends `YouTubeBaseActivity`, and it works.

You need to set the style/theme that has an `ActionBar` or `Toolbar` which contains menu, and it will call the method.

You can take look at project [here](https://github.com/jbj88817/YoutubeSample-android), clone it, and try yourself. Click `Simple PlayerView` and it will pop up `ActionBar` with menu which call the method.

Basically, I add the two method [here](https://github.com/jbj88817/YoutubeSample-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/examples/youtubeapidemo/YouTubeFailureRecoveryActivity.java#L58-L77) and set the style/theme for the activity [here](https://github.com/jbj88817/YoutubeSample-android/blob/master/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml#L60).

And it called the menu method as follows:

[image]

Comment: My app running but actionbar inside show home icon.how to icon visible?

Comment: Can you provide the screenshot for this please, you can edit your question.